# Need help using the Python Library Chemspipy to post a request

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, soap

I want to use ChemSpiPy to search the ChemSpider database for a compound using the filter-name-post method which is documented [here](https://developer.rsc.org/compounds-v1/apis/post/filter/name) However, I am not sure what parameters I'm supposed to enter into the library's post function. In the [documentation](https://chemspipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#chemspipy-api) it says the parameters are supposed to be the following:

```
post(api, namespace, endpoint, json=None)[source]

Convenience method for making POST requests.
Parameters: 

    api (string) – Top-level API, e.g. compounds.
    namespace (string) – API namespace, e.g. filter, lookups, records, or     tools.
    endpoint (string) – Web service endpoint URL.
    json (dict) – JSON data to send in the request body.

Returns:    

Web Service response content.
Return type:    

dict or string
```

My Code currently looks like this:

```
from chemspipy import ChemSpider

cs = ChemSpider('<API KEY>')
compound_name = input('search for: ')
requestbody = {
    "name": compound_name,
    "orderBy": "",
    "orderDirection": ""
}
print(cs.post('compounds', 'filter-name-post', 'https://api.rsc.org/compounds/v1/filter/name', requestbody))
```

Running this code and entering something like 'carbon' returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the path to my script", line 12, in <module>
    print(cs.post('filter', 'filter-name-post', 'https://api.rsc.org/compounds/v1/filter/name', requestbody))
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\chemspipy\api.py", line 181, in post
    return self.request('POST', api=api, namespace=namespace, endpoint=endpoint, json=json)  
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\chemspipy\api.py", line 154, in request
    raise err(message=r.reason, http_code=r.status_code)
chemspipy.errors.ChemSpiPyNotFoundError: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```py
from chemspipy import ChemSpider
cs = ChemSpider("<API KEY>")

requestbody = {
    "name": "carbon",
    "orderBy": "",
    "orderDirection": "",
}

print(cs.post('compounds', 'filter', 'name', requestbody))
```

Comment: this returned {'queryId': 'edf8597f-0230-4621-87f2-45e573834904'}
 how do we get the results?